# Cardinality of infinite product?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is the cardinality of an infinite product easily expressed in simpler terms?

The specific problem is this. Suppose $\alpha$ is a countable limit ordinal. The set I want to count has size equal to $\Pi_{\beta<\alpha} \beth_\beta$.

I would like the output to be $\beth_\alpha$ but honestly I'm not sure how this works out. Finite cardinal multiplication is very easy, but I don't know anything about infinite products like this.  Certainly I can bound it above; $\beth_\beta<\beth_\alpha$, so the product has size at most $\beth_\alpha^\omega$, but by Konig's theorem this is strictly larger than $\beth_\alpha$ and doesn't sit well with me.

Comment: Nothing much can be said about infinite product of cardinals. Sure we can say this and that. But something *concrete*? Not very often.

Comment: So in this case, is it likely to say "it's at most $\beth_\alpha^\omega$" and leave it there?

Comment: I have to disagree with Asaf, though I figure it is really that we interpret the quantifier "nothing much" in different ways. For a general result in particular containing the computation you are asking, see theorem 13 in [this](https://andrescaicedo.wordpress.com/2009/02/09/580-cardinal-arithmetic-3/) blog post (which refers to [this one](https://andrescaicedo.wordpress.com/2009/02/07/580-cardinal-arithmetic-2/)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this *does* have a nice answer.  I originally had a much more complicated proof, and almost immediately afterward, a simple one was given to be by Douglas Ulrich.  The answer is that for any limit ordinal $\alpha$, $\prod_{\beta<\alpha} \beth_\beta=\beth_{\alpha+1}$.  What follows is a proof in more detail than is maybe necessary.

The essential reason is the $\prod_i 2^{\kappa_i}=2^{\sum_i \kappa_i}$, which is easily verified.  This gives us the following:

$\prod_{\beta<\alpha}\beth_\beta=\prod_{\beta<\alpha}2^{\beth_\beta}$; this is seen by seeing both sides inject naturally into the other.  Left to right is that $\beth_\beta\leq 2^{\beth_\beta}$, while right to left is because this is a product of a smaller set (since $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal).

Then $\prod_{\beta<\alpha}2^{\beth_\beta}=2^{\sum_\beta\beth_\beta}$.  Clearly $\sum_\beta\beth_\beta=\beth_\alpha$, so this last is $2^{\beth_\alpha}=\beth_{\alpha+1}$, as desired.